# How to change style of Selected ListView Item in UWP

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, listviewitem, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView in my UWP application with this code.

```
<ListView Name="menuListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" 
              BorderThickness="0,0,0,5" SelectedIndex="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="dayTB"  Text="Day" Margin="25 0 0 0" FontSize="18" />
        <TextBlock Name="weekTB" Text="Week" Margin="25 0 0 0" FontSize="18" />
        <TextBlock Name="monthTB" Text="Month" Margin="25 0 0 0" FontSize="18" />

    </ListView>
```

It looks like this.

[image]

I am trying to make it look like this for quite some time now, but my tries are not successful.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right control used in the picture, is the Pivot, not ListView.

try this basic Pivot XAML code, and play around it

```
<Pivot Title="EMAIL">
<PivotItem Header="All">
<TextBlock Text="all emails go here." />
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem Header="Unread">
<TextBlock Text="unread emails go here." />
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem Header="Flagged">
<TextBlock Text="flagged emails go here." />
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem Header="Urgent">
<TextBlock Text="urgent emails go here." />
</PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```